# How to remove 4 byte unicode symbols in Python 2?

Tags: python, mysql, unicode

I have some problem with differents in one string after adding it to database.

I have string "space 222 m²". If I write it to mysql via mysqldb module I got "space 222 m²" in table, which is ok. But when I got this value from table, after decoding I get something like "space 222 m\eb000\b1111", which is not "space 222 m²".

This string before adding to database in unicode looks like "space 222 m\xcb", but on print it's displayed right, string from database is displayed with unicode codes and in consequence giving error.

- MySQL charset - utf-8
- Database collation - utf8_general_ci
- Source string - utf-8

And i have problems with integrate string with special characters with other string without that

```
## db it's mongodb
st=db.objects.find()[0]['value']
string=st.encode('utf-8') # can be with m² or not. Encoding identical
some_string=u"some"
x="%s %s"%(string,some_string)
```

if string not contains special symbols all fine,
but if string contains special symbols i got UnicodeDecodeError

Python version:

**Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32**

Comment: Please provide your version of Python, how exactly and where exactly you're seeing this output, and relevant code for inserting/fetching/outputting these values.

Comment: look example in first post

Comment: See if [_my Python notes_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python) help any.

Comment: Superscript 2 is hex `C2B2` in utf8 or Unicode codepoint `00B2`.  I don't know where you are getting `\eb000\b1111` from.

Answer (score 0):

**a note on UTF-8:** There are different ISO character sets within UTF-8, so keep that in mind when sending data from your UI to the DB. Have a look at localization and character encoding\sets this will help you a lot in understanding unicode\ascii.

I don't know the exact mappings of your strings, but to answer your question try `get_string().encode('utf-8')`
and `get_string().decode('utf-8')`

Comment: I add details to example code. and decoding source string cause an error

Comment: *"There are different ISO character sets within UTF-8"* – wut? Please clarify.

Comment: Unicode is a character set. UTF-8\16 is an encoding. Encoding translates numbers into binary. Character sets translates characters to numbers.

Comment: Right, so how are there "different ISO character sets within UTF-8"? That statement makes no sense.

Comment: @deceze - Lets take the same character in two charsets, the characters numeric value in a unicode charset might not represent the same numeric value in another ISO charset although the character looks the same in both charsets. So if your DB saved it as encoding UTF8 using Unicode charset but next time your python reads the UTF8 as culture code page ISO xxx then you wouldn't get the same character representation. You can save a character (from character set) to any encoding but you need to decode it to the correct charset i.e. unicode, latin, iso, marc and etc

Comment: Yes, exactly. Believe me, I understand all this. The original statement still makes no sense.

Comment: @deceze - I agree, maybe I shouldn't have said "...character sets within UTF8"  but rather "... CAN store different character set using UTF8" as the  latter would've been more acceptable.

Comment: You probably just mean *"the UTF-8/Unicode charset is a superset of virtually all other character sets."*

Comment: @deceze - No, UTF-8 is an encoding not a charset.